# Dreamweaver, Android, Eclipse--using files from Dreamweaver in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, dreamweaver

I have been like a tiger chasing its tail for weeks.

Dreamweaver 5.5 simply will not consistently compile my mobile Android programs. I found a fix that worked for a while and then suddenly stopped. I've found Adobe's official fix.(http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/924/cpsid_92492.html) Nothing works.

As a work around, I'm trying to figure out how to import the generated Dreamweaver files into Eclipse so that I can build the .apx file. This is the workaround that I'm also using with Xcode since Dreamweaver 5.5 doesn't work as expected there either. (Makes me pretty furious since I paid a small fortune for DW 5.5 just because Adobe advertised it for mobile devices. A company of Adobe's size should produce a product that works as stated.)

This issue isn't just mine, many people are and have complained about it.

At any rate, **can someone tell me how to import the DW generated files into Eclipse** so that I can generate the needed build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you Mr.User1204493. There is no documentation available as how to import the generated Dreamweaver PhoneGap Site files into Eclipse IDE for Android Platform.

I am currently using Dreamweaver CS6 Trail Version to build a PhoneGap application.

Maybe this solution will help you - I copied all the files generated in the Dreamweaver site folder and pasted it in `assets/www` folder. As it is the same `index.html`, you need not change anything in your MainActivity.

It worked initially for a hello world application and displayed correctly in the Android Emulator, but now my `PhoneGap` application with 5 HTML pages works just fine in `Dreamweaver CS6`, but its not working on Eclipse.

When i try to run the application it shows a blank white screen for like 2 mins and then a black screen for 30 seconds and then throws an error `E/Web Console(302): SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent`. at `file:///android_asset/www/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js:70`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I never have conquered the Emulator issues, but appreciate your attempt to help. I am generating iOS using 5.5 and Xcode. Gave up on Android. Sorry it took me a while to get back to you. -Rachel